# MSM Merge modules in Visual studio 2013 : Dependency not detected

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, installation, windows-installer

I migrated a visual C++ solution containing 70+ projects to VS2013 Update 5 from VS2008 SP1. The VS2008 SP1 was using merge modules and in VS2013 I am using this [plugin](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d) to achieve this functionality. However, the merge module is not detecting external dependencies of the dlls I am building. For example, one of the dll is dependent on ace.dll (and specifies ace.lib in linker->input) but that dependency is not detected. In VS2008, the same dependency was detected. Any idea what could be wrong or where to look for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that it previously detected that dependency in the VS 2008 setup project. To my knowledge, there is no link between the VS 2008 development project that you might be using to build your code and the dependencies in the setup project.

a) You can drag and drop files from anywhere into your setup project. There's no requirement that a VS setup project generate an MSI file from the files in your VS 2008 project.

b) A dependency on a particular Dll cannot result in that Dll being included in the setup because a huge number of dependent Dlls are included in separate redistributables. These Dlls might even be in the prerequisites of the setup project and that's how they get installed. You don't want (for example) every Crystal Reports Dll, SQL Dll etc in your MSI setup because they are required to be installed via redistributables or their own merge modules. There is no grand database of every Dll and which redistributable or merge module should be used to deploy it, so VS projects certainly don't know.

c) Not all dependencies can be detected by looking at the binary file. COM dependencies are not listed anywhere in a binary because they're linked dynamically via guids, so they can never be detected that way.

In general the bad news is that the developer needs to know which dependencies need to be installed individually, which come in redist setups, and which are standad Dlls, such as those that are part of the OS and never need installing.